# Query for two fields within an array, then return another array entry

Tags: mongodb

I am storing the details of a report structure in the DB. The hierarchy is

```
ReportId (Primary key)
  Report_Options (has multiple options)
     Option_Value (Each Option can value multiple values - see JSON below)
     Option_Weight (numerical int value for Option_Value)
  Templates (Multiple templates in ReportID, each corresponding to a combination of options)
     TemplateID
     TemplateOptionWeight (array of valid product[Option_weight])
```

JSON Structure:

```
{"ReportId": "RPTPIN001",  
 "ReportDesc": "Monthly Sales report", 
 "ReportCat":"Sales",
 "ReportOpt":
     [
      { "Label": "Weekly Summary",
        "OptionType":"Boolean",
        "OptionValues":["Yes", "No"],
        "OptionWeight":[1,2]
      },
      { "Label": "Comapre to",
        "OptionType":"dropdown",
        "OptionValues":["Prev Month", "Prev Qtr" , "Prev Year"],
        "OptionWeight":[3,4,5]
      }
     ],
 
  "Templates":
            [
              {"TemplateId": "FTLPIN001", 
               "TemplateData":"xxxxxxxxx",
               "TemplateOptionWeight":[3,4,5]
              } ,
              {"TemplateId": "FTLPIN002", 
               "TemplateData":"yyyyyyyy",
               "TemplateOptionWeight":[6,8,10]
              }    
                
            ]  
  }
```

If the user chooses "Weekly Summary=No" [OptionWeight=2] and "Compare To = Prev Year" [OptionWeight=5] , how can I return "TemplateId": "FTLPIN002"?

Since the product of Options_weights is 5*2 = 10 and FTLPIN002 has an array element of 10 in TemplateOptionWeight

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. How does the user know which reportId to query for based on only two report options? What if other reports have the exact same options? Do you want those templates as well?

Comment: My question is:  If the user chooses "Weekly Summary=No" [OptionWeight=2] and "Compare To = Prev Year" [OptionWeight=5] , I need to return "TemplateId": "FTLPIN002"..  What is the query that will return  {"TemplateId": "FTLPIN002", 
               "TemplateData":"yyyyyyyy",
               "TemplateOptionWeight":[6,8,10]

Comment: And, what if there are multiple documents with the same opts, but different templates?

Comment: There really is no way that I see to even query for `Weekly Summary = No`. You can query for a `Report Opt.label = "Weekly Summary"` for example, but then your application would need to iterate the returned values (for every matching report) and their weight arrays to find the weight for `No`...the better design would be another object array like `options: [{value: No, weight: 2}, {value: Yes, weight: 1}]`